# In what ways member functions may be compared to each other?

Tags: c++, function, operator-overloading, compare

I would like to know if I can compare 2 member functions with the "<" operator. I can do "==" but I can't use it in the case below. I tried casting them to **void*** but that won't work either.

```
template <class Receiver, class Sender>
class CallBack2 : public ICallBack2 {

protected:

    Receiver* receiver;
    void(Receiver::*function)(Sender*);
    Sender* sender;

public:

    CallBack2(Receiver* _receiver, void(Receiver::*_function)(Sender*), Sender* _sender) : receiver(_receiver), function(_function), sender(_sender) {};
    virtual ~CallBack2() {};

    virtual void callBack() {
        (receiver->*function)(sender);
    }

    virtual bool operator<(const ICallBack2* _other) const {
        CallBack2<Receiver, Sender>* other = (CallBack2<Receiver, Sender>*)_other;
        if (receiver < other->receiver) {
            return true;
        } else if (receiver == other->receiver && function < other->function) {
            return true; // this line gives the error
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: What would be the meaning of `function1 < function2`?

Comment: I need a constant comparison result in order to put them in a std::set or std::map

Comment: @Bill Kotsias Then implement a function that returns a result. And you can use that one or change the signature of this function.

Comment: @Bill Kostias, you should edit your question to reflect what you are actually trying to do.  You want to put member functions into a std::set or std::map.  You tried using an `operator<` as shown but it doesn't work.

Comment: By the way, you can write lexicographic comparison compactly like this: `return A.x < B.x || (A.x == B.x && A.y  < B.y)`; or if you don't want to mix operators, `return A.x < B.x || (!(B.x < A.x) && A.y  < B.y)`.

Comment: @andrewdski: I believe that the question does reflect what the questioner is trying to do. He is trying to put `CallBack2` objects into a set or map, and therefore is trying to define `operator<` for that template. The attempt is shown in the question. Since the `Receiver` data member doesn't have a well-defined order, there's a problem.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: wanting to put member functions in a set/map is a generally useful question that other people might ask.  Obtaining a working `operator<` is necessary for doing that, of course.  The specific code presented may not be the only/best way of building that operator.  (I admit, it may very well be impossible.)  My real point was, if the question included the actual goal, it would make it a better question (by stackoverflow standards).

Comment: @Bill: btw, to be correct you should probably use `std::less(received, other->receiver)` rather than `<`. Pointers aren't guaranteed to be comparable with `<` unless they're to subobjects of a common object, although in practice it'll work because everyone has flat memory space these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to arbitrarily order them to be keys in a set/map, then you can `reinterpret_cast` them. You may need a template class like `exact_int<sizeof(void (Foo::*bar)())>::type` because [pointers to member functions can have funny sizes](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx).

Comment: I don't think that works either. AFAIK there is no guarantee that `reinterpret_cast`s of equal pointer-to-member-function values are equal. There could be padding bytes/bits in the ptr-to-mem-fun, which take arbitrary values and are ignored by `operator==` for ptr-to-mem-fun, but not by `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score 3):

C++03 [§ 5.9](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/open/n2356/expr.html#expr.rel), which covers the semantics of the built-in <, >, <= and >=, doesn't mention pointers to members and states:

> Other pointer comparisons are unspecified.

According to [§ 8.3.3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/open/n2356/decl.html#dcl.mptr), 3

> The type "pointer to member" is distinct from the type "pointer",

As a result, we can conclude the result of relational operators applied to pointers to members (whether functions or fields) is unspecified.

Note that "unspecified behavior" is different from "undefined behavior", but still means you can't usefully apply the operators as different implementations may have different results. "Unspecified" basically means the implementation gets to define the behavior.

Comment: Fortunately in this case it doesn't matter, since "Other pointer comparisons are unspecified". A pointer-to-member-function type isn't a pointer-to-function type, but perhaps it's ambiguous whether a member function is a function or not, for the purposes of that sentence? I'd expect that if it meant to include member functions it would say so, but that's based on the fact that the pointer types are different, rather than on me knowing anywhere that the standard states that a member function is not a function. It is.

Comment: 5.10 (equality operators) deals explicitly with member functions, and the wording about function is the same. So this means that @Steve may be right: "Other pointer comparisons are unspecified"

Comment: "Unspecified" doesn't basically mean "implementation-defined" if you have access to the implementation documentation, since the former doesn't have to be documented, whereas the latter does. When trying to write portable code, you generally have to avoid both of them, though, unless the standard restricts behavior within bounds that you can cope with, for example "it is unspecified whether X or Y", and you're happy with either.

Comment: Pointer to member functions indeed aren't considered pointers to functions. Answer updated to quote parts of standard relevant to question.

Comment: In this case "Unspecified" means that a comparison operator for sure always returns either `true` or `false`, but we cannot predict the return value. Saves us from UB, but is pretty useless anyway.

Answer (score 1):

5.9.7 (relational operators): "Other pointer comparisons are unspecified".

Since 5.9 is unclear (it deals with functions, but not explicitly member functions), a quick look at 5.10 (equality comparison) clearly separates *functions* from *member functions*:

> In addition, pointers to members can be compared, or a pointer to
>   member and a null pointer constant. Pointer to member conversions
>   (4.11) and qualification conversions (4.4) are performed to bring them
>   to a common type. If one operand is a null pointer constant, the
>   common type is the type of the other operand. Otherwise, the common
>   type is a pointer to member type similar (4.4) to the type of one of
>   the operands, with a cv-qualification signature (4.4) that is the
>   union of the cv-qualification signatures of the operand types. [Note:
>   this implies that any pointer to member can be compared to a null
>   pointer constant. ] If both operands are null, they compare equal.
>   Otherwise if only one is null, they compare unequal. Otherwise if
>   either is a pointer to a virtual member function, the result is
>   unspecified. Otherwise they compare equal if and only if they would
>   refer to the same member of the same most derived object (1.8) or the
>   same subobject if they were dereferenced with a hypothetical object of
>   the associated class type.

So you can use the operators, the meaning of `==` and `!=` is specified, but the meaning of `<`, `>`, `<=` and `>=` is unspecified.

In particular, nothing enforces transitivity, so it is not clear whether putting them in a set is ok or not.

Answer (score 1):

Though the description gets a little lengthy, how about having a dummy
variable and comparing its pointer like the following?

```
template< class T >
struct comparable_value {
    T value;
    char *id;

    comparable_value( T value, char* id ) : value( value ), id( id ) {}

    bool operator<( comparable_value const& x ) const {
        return std::less< char* >()( id, x.id );
    }
};

template< class T, T V >
comparable_value< T > get_comparable_value() {
    static char dummy;
    return comparable_value< T >( V, &dummy );
}

struct A {
    void f() { puts( "f" ); }
    void g() { puts( "g" ); }
};

int main() {
    typedef void (A::*MF)();
    typedef std::set< comparable_value< MF > > set_t;
    set_t s;
    s.insert( get_comparable_value< MF, &A::f >() );
    s.insert( get_comparable_value< MF, &A::g >() );
    A a;
    for ( set_t::iterator i = s.begin(), e = s.end();  i != e;  ++ i )
        (a.*i->value)();
}
```

Here is a test on [ideone](http://ideone.com/ltefn).

Comment: Looks like the comparable things have to be acquired with the ptr-to-mem-fun as a compile-time constant (to use it as a template parameter), so works if whoever provides the ptr in the first place can also provide its comparable equivalent.

Comment: @SteveJessop:
Yes, if the OP takes this way, `function` member in `CallBack2` in the
question will have to be
`comparable_value< void(Receiver::*)(Sender*) >` instead of
member pointer itself,
and the user of `CallBack2` will have to call `get_comparable_value`
when constructing `CallBack2`.
However, I'm not sure this is really applicable in the OP's situation.
Even if possible, the code will get much lengthy.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like Ise's idea, only keep it contained to Callback2 class so that you don't need to change anything that uses the class.

```
template <class Receiver, class Sender>class CallBack2 : public ICallBack2 {
private:
   static int nextSequenceNumber;
   int sequenceNumber;

//snip

public:
  CallBack2(Receiver* _receiver, void(Receiver::*_function)(Sender*), Sender* _sender) :
   sequenceNumber(nextSequenceNumber++), receiver(_receiver), function(_function), sender(_sender) {};

//snip

virtual bool operator<(const ICallBack2* _other) const {
  return sequenceNumber<_other->sequenceNumber;}
```

Comment: Good idea but it wouldn't be able to say that two CallBack2 objects are the same when Receiver and Receiver::*function are equal. It will always assume they are different which is unwanted behavior.

Comment: @Bill You could test for equivalence before testing the sequence number.

Answer (score -1):

Taking the address of a member function results in a constant expression that cannot be stored in a variable. It can only be used to compare for equality to another expression that represenst the address of a function taking the same set of parameters, with the same return type and the same type of this pointer.

```
    class a 
    {
    public:
        virtual void test();
    };
    class b
    {
    public:
        virtual void test();
    };

    ....
    a *pa = new a;
    b *pb = new b;

    if (pb->test == pa->test) // legal, but  false
    if (pb->test==pb::test) // legal and true
    // pa->test will evaluate to a::test, although calling pa->test() would call
    // b::test()
```

Comment: `void (a::*pfa)(void) = &a::test;`. Pointer to member function, stored in a variable.

Comment: @Steve, Thanks, I didn't know that! How would you then use pfa to call it on an object? Just curious.

Comment: `(pa->*pfa)()`. `->*` and `.*` are the pointer-to-member dereference operators. The mnemonic is that `*pfa` is the member, and hence `pa->*pfa` accesses that member (via the pointer `pa`), but actually `->*` is a single operator.

Comment: @steve, did you intent the '&' in &a::test? I thought mentioning a function without '()' is taking the address, so a::test is the address of the member function. If you write &pa->test, would the compiler generate code to consult 'pa''s virtual method table at runtime?

Comment: Yes I meant it, although I think you're right, it can be left out. Yes, a call to a ptr-to-mem-fun where the function is virtual can be used to make a virtual call.

Answer (score -1):

It makes no sense to compare two function pointers. What you could compare is actually the return value of those functions:

```
*function(sender) < *(other->function)(sender)
```

but in your case you declare the function as:

```
void(Receiver::*function)(Sender*);
```

so, in my opinion. Comparing the functions is useless. Either change the function's signature to return something or better describe your business scenario so we can better understand what you want.

Comment: Comparing the function pointers isn't useless, the question shows what it's for -- defining `operator<` on `Callback2`, presumably to be consistent with `==`. You're right the comparison "makes no sense", but it also makes no sense to compare pointers that aren't to subobjects of a common object, and yet the standard provides `std::less` for pointer types precisely for this purpose: associative containers only require consistency, not sense. But that's only for pointer types, not ptr-to-mem-fun types. The return value of a call to the functions is nothing to do with what the questioner wants.

Comment: thank you for the comment. Comparing pointers of objects using relational operators makes sense just for objects that reside in the same array (thus comparing their relative positions) but not in this kind of case. That's why I suggested to implement a separate function that returns a valid result. I still don't understand why you would -1 this. Here is a couple of links to support this argument: http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter5/pointer_expressions.html , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5wt12d.aspx

Comment: `std:less<T*>` works for *all* pointers-to-object, not just pointers for which `p1 < p2` works. The reason is so that you can have a `set` or `map` whose key type is a pointer, and whose members are not all in the same array. But the analogous extra requirement is missing for ptr-to-mem-fun, not because it makes any less sense but (I think) because it's expected to be harder to implement. Anyway, the -1 is mostly for "IMO, comparing is useless", when the OP's code clearly shows the desired use.