# Function and method pointers in a std::set

Tags: c++, stl, comparison, set, function-pointers

As described [in another message of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662917/in-what-ways-member-functions-may-be-compared-to-each-other), it is not possible to compare 2 pointers to member functions with **"<" (less than)**. Or at least, this causes undefined behavior.

I have just managed to compile this code both with Visual C++ as well as GCC:

```
template <class Receiver, class Param = void*, class Return = void>
class EventReceiver : public IFunction<> {

protected:

    std::set< Return(Receiver::*)(Param) > test;
    std::set< Return(*)(Param) > test2;
...
```

AFAIK, to make a std::map or std::set of anything, it must be possible to compare the set's values with "<". Does this mean that the above containers or the actual compilers have a working implementation of comparing pointers-to-methods in such a way?

Comment: My answer was incorrect - pointers-to-member and pointers are not the same.  My apologies!

Comment: @templatetypedef FWIW the corresponding wording in the C++11 is under § 20.8.5/8. This _is_ puzzling. I invited some (compiler-building) friends to have a say here

Comment: @Xeo has given an idea [in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2582471#2582471)

Comment: Nice one, but I am really not interested in RTTI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it was in reality **misleading** that the example code compiled. The truth is that the sets are **unusable**. Every attempt to insert data into them produces the expected error.

That's the "dark side" of C++ template functions. They don't exist till you use them (and thus won't produce compiler errors till you do).

Check this out :

```
#include <set>

class X {};

int main() {

    typedef void(X::*FuncPtr)();
    std::set< FuncPtr > set;
    std::less< FuncPtr > less;
    FuncPtr f1;
    FuncPtr f2;
    //set.insert(f1);   // both of these lines
    //less(f1,f2);      // produce an error
};
```

Removing the comments in any of the last 2 lines produces the error :

> invalid operands of types ‘void (X::* const)()’ and ‘void (X::*
>   const)()’ to binary ‘operator<’

[Compile it online yourself here](http://ideone.com/sNITH).

Answer (score 0):

`std::set<T>` uses `std::less<T>`, instead of using the less-than operator directly. When `T` is a pointer type, `std::less<T>` is guaranteed to be a total order, even if the less-than operator does not.

Edit: Section 20.3.3 of the C++98 standard says "pointer types", which (I think) includes pointers to functions, but not pointers to members.

Comment: "the specializations for any pointer type yield a total order, even if the built-in operators <, >, <=, >= do not." -- Now the question is, is a "pointer to member" type also a "pointer" type? The standard seems to say no, see the other question.

Comment: Well, std::less doesn't work either! [ std::less<Return(Receiver::*)(Param)>().operator()(function, other->function)) ] doesn't compile : error C2296: '<' : illegal, left operand has type 'void (__thiscall Fair::PtrIcon::* const )(Fair::Pointer *)' !!!

Comment: @Xeo: Visual C++ 2010 Express, its own x86 compiler as well as a GCC ARM compiler. Won't your example compile for you?